# How can I search in a data frame if all possible combinations exist in another data frame in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames.

The first one that contains all the possible combinations with their corresponding values and looks like this:

| first | second | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| A | C | 20 |
| A | D | 30 |
| B | C | 40 |
| B | D | 50 |
| C | D | 60 |
| H | I | 70 |

The second one that comes from the production line has two columns the date column that has grouped all the variables corresponding to their date and are concatenated:

| date | var |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A |
| 2022-02-01 | B,C,F,E,G,H,I |

I want to find all the combinations in the second data frame and to see if they match with any combinations in the first data frame. If a variable stands alone in the second data frame as A in 2022-01-01 to give me the 0 and otherwise the value of the combination.

Ideally I want the resulting data frame to look like this:

| date | comb | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 | B,C | 40 |
| 2022-02-01 | H,I | 70 |

How can I do this in R using [dplyr](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/dplyr.html)?

```
library(tidyverse)
first = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","H")
second = c("B","C","D","C","D","D","I")
val = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
df1 = tibble(first,second,val);df1
date = c(as.Date("2022-01-01"),as.Date("2022-02-01"))
var = c("A","B,C,F,E,G,H,I")
df2  = tibble(date,var);df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
first = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","H")
second = c("B","C","D","C","D","D","I")
val = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
df1 = tibble(first,second,val);df1
date = c(as.Date("2022-01-01"),as.Date("2022-02-01"))
var = c("A","B,C,F,E,G,H,I")
df2  = tibble(date,var);df2 

df2_tidy <- df2 %>%
  mutate(first = str_split(var, ","),
         second = first) %>%
  unnest(first) %>%
  unnest(second) %>%
  select(-var)

singles <- df2 %>%
  filter(!str_detect(var, ",")) %>%
  mutate(val = 0) %>%
  select(date, comb = var, val)

combs <- df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2_tidy, by = c("first", "second")) %>%
  mutate(comb = paste(first, second, sep = ",")) %>%
  select(date, comb, val)

bind_rows(singles, combs)
```

Comment: While it answer the question I have thought a additional one.In the singles df, how the  `filter(nchar(var) == 1)` can be modified if instead of a single letter was a name without pair.For example it was "George",not "A" because `nchar(var) ==1` is for a single letter.

Comment: We can check instead that no comma is in the string. I'm updating the answer with this.